# I want to use NRF24L01 transceiver with raspberry pi but some GPIO pins are already occupied by 3.5 inch display how do i connect transceiver

Tags: raspbian, gpio, display, arduino, nrf24l01

26 GPIO pins are already used by 3.5 inch display some of these occupied pins are needed to connect transceiver. I am using NRF24L01 for wireless communication between raspberryPi and arduino

can i use breadboard and connect pins parallelly.

Comment: yes you can, a breadboard is a good way to make multiple connections to a pin, but you should really be asking if you can connect both modules to the RPi in parallel

Comment: does the display really use all of the pins?

Comment: @jsotola i. have no idea whether display is using all 26 pins or not but it has occupied 26 pins... is it right to do parallel connect is pins like 3V3, 5V, I2C SDA, UART TX/RX... so on

Comment: we don't  know either, becuse it is not known what  you have and how you are connecting it

Comment: Yes, you can use a breadboard to connect pins in parallel. I think, in the near future, it will be more convenient if you make a  NRF24L01 HAT like this but with two way header. https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/Raspberry_Pi_NRF24L01_Hat_2_d4468a2b.html  The HAT shown here has male headers only. But if you use Two-way headers, you can easily accommodate a display above.